# keras - is it possible to make an entire model or sequence of layers repeat recursively?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to do something like the following:

```
count = 0
myinput = Input(shape=(100,5))
#this is where we return to
while count < 10:
  lstm1 = LSTM(5,return_sequences=True)(myinput)
  merged = Concatenate(axis=1)([lstm1,myinput])  #I think that's the right axis lol.  Just an example
  myinput = LSTM(5,return_sequences=True)(merged)
  count += 1

result = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(myinput)
```

This is just an example, I wouldn't never want to make a network specifically like this.  But anyways, this code would of course make a sequence of layers corresponding to the specifications of lstm1, merged, myinput - and repeat that sequence 10 times.  So, 30 different layers.

I only want 3 layers, I want it to re-use the layers in the while loop.  Which would mean that only after a specific number of repetitions does lstm1 no longer accept input.  Otherwise, the network would go on forever.

Is this something that is possible?
Thank you.

Comment: are you looking something similar to ResNet?

Comment: I don't believe so, I'm not super familiar with resnets but I believe that they are primarily feedforward.  I basically want my entire network to be wrapped in some sort of simple recurrent layer that lets it take in an input a set amount of times

Comment: So,there would be a new input feed into the layers at each iteration?

Comment: in this example yes, but I also have ideas I'd like to implement where the input to lstm1 might actually be the same every iteration, but then later in the sequence it might do some sort of merge with the outputs from earlier iterations.

but the simple answer here:  yes

Comment: I think what you looking for is a skip connection,where the output from one layers concatenate with input of the other layers in model.

Comment: But if I have lstm1 output going to lstm2, is it possible to have lstm2 merge with the input of lstm1 and feed back into it?  If so, how can I do that?

Comment: [check out this docs](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aware that:

- You are increasing the number of steps for each iteration. (Start with 100, next 200, next 300, etc.)

Then it's quite easy:

```
originalInput = Input((100,5))
myinput = originalInput

lstm1 = LSTM(5,return_sequences=True)
lstm2 = LSTM(5,return_sequences=True)

for i in range(10):
    out = lstm1(myinput)
    out = Concatenate(axis=1)([out, myinput])
    out = lstm2(out)
    myinput = out

model = Model(originalInput, out)
```

---

Concatenation axes:

- 0: samples or examples (batch size) - you would hardly ever change this
- 1: time steps (initially 100)
- 2: units or features (5)

Comment: ohhhhhhh

so my mistake is declaring the LSTMs in the loop.
geeze, this makes perfect sense